# In Javascript, after deleting key in object, rename remaining keys using sequential numbers

Tags: javascript, object, rename

```
filters = { 1: { stat: 'a' }, 2: { stat: 'b' }, 3: { stat: 'c'} }
delete filters[1]
```

Filters is now `2: { stat: 'b' }, 3: { stat: 'c'} }`, however we need the lowest key to equal 1, the 2nd lowest key to equal 2, and so on. In the example above, we deleted the lowest key, which requires renaming of keys. In the situation where we deleted `key == 3`, obviously no renaming of keys would be required.

Order matters in the sense that, in the example above, `key == 2` needs to be renamed to 1, and `key == 3` then needs to be renamed to 2. `key == 3` cannot simply be renamed to 1.

Comment: Why would you ever do this instead of just using an array and utilising its indexes?

Comment: i = the key you deleted
loop over all the keys starting with i and do
filters[i] = filters[i+1]
i++
Or something similar.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan that's a good question, I do think array is the better structure now that I think more about it.

Comment: As I refactor the code, it continues to seem like array is the better structure

Answer (score 2):

Maybe consider using an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). The work will be a bit different, but will probably be what you want.

Note: It will start at 0, not at 1.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a collection of numeric indexed keys in sequential ascending order with easy rearrangement when a value is removed - then use an array, not an object.

```js
const filters = [{ stat: 'a' }, { stat: 'b' }, { stat: 'c'}];
filters.splice(1, 1); // remove 1 item from index 1 of the array
console.log(filters);

// if you need to use the original structure somewhere too,
// transform it when needed:
const filtersObj = Object.fromEntries(
  filters.map((obj, i) => [i + 1, obj])
);
console.log(filtersObj);
```